# Hangfire job is throwing an error when I start my project

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am trying to schedule a Hangfire job like this:

In my Startup.cs, I have this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => sb.AddSendItems(), "0 7 * * 5");
```

And the method is async:

```
public async void AddSendItems()
{

   //...add items to database and 3rd party scheduler

}
```

It builds fine, but when I try to run it, I get this:

```
System.NotSupportedException
  Message=Async void methods are not supported. Use async Task instead.
  Source=Hangfire.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Hangfire.Common.Job.Validate(Type type, String typeParameterName, MethodInfo method, String methodParameterName, Int32 argumentCount, String argumentParameterName)
```

I checked the Hangfire documentation here, and they do support async:

https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/index.html?highlight=asynchronous

Has anyone had this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message suggests.
"Async void methods are not supported. **Use async Task instead.**"

```
public async Task AddSendItems()
{
   //...add items to database and 3rd party scheduler
}
```